# BufferedImage turns all black after scaling via canvas

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

I have a method which purpose is to receive an image and return it scaled down.
The reason I'm using canvas is that I believe that it will scale the image automatically for me.

After the conversion the outputimage is completely black. Anyone have any clue on how to fix this?

```
try {
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(f.getBytes());
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);

        File beforescale = new File("beforescale.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", beforescale);  //works

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setSize(100, 100);
        canvas.paint(image.getGraphics());

        image = canvasToImage(canvas);
        File outputfile = new File("testing.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputfile); //all black

        response.getWriter().print(canvas);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private BufferedImage canvasToImage(Canvas cnvs) {
    int w = cnvs.getWidth();
    int h = cnvs.getHeight();
    int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB;
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w,h,type);
    Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
    cnvs.paint(g2);
    g2.dispose();
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, here you use [canvas#paint(Graphics)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29) to paint the *image on the canvas*:

```
    canvas.paint(image.getGraphics());
```

And here you canvas#paint(Graphics) again to paint the *canvas on the image*:

```
    cnvs.paint(g2);
```

Obviously one of these two fails. You can only use this method to paint the canvas on the image.

The solution is to use [getScaledInstance()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29) on `image`.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
Image smallerImg = image.getScaledInstance(100,100,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
ImageIO.write(smallerImg, "jpg", outputfile);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've read that getScaledInstance doesn't produce good results, and that's why I tried getting around it. Is that still true? ( http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html )

Comment: @Emil - From that article `the general complaint is about poor performance.`. Not sure if this is true, is it too slow for you? Using canvas probably won't help, because I guess it uses `getScaledInstance()` to scale anyway. If you want to use a different route, pick one of those mentioned in the article?